# JCIFS: is possible get a file and use like BufferedReader?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, samba

I've a method that returns a BufferedReader, something like this:

```
File file = new File(fileName);
try {
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
}
catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
    ex.getStackTrace();
}
```

How can I get a file with JCIFS API and return a BufferedReader?

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: This is the comlete example:                                  SmbFile fileSamba = new SmbFile(path, auth);           SmbFileInputStream fstream = new SmbFileInputStream(sambaFile);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));